# Count showing as undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, count

I am trying to add the count function inside of my loop so that the users displayed will be given an order number. Like this...

1. user1
2. user2
3. user3
   etc

As of now, the count number displays as undefined.

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($array as $result) :
$count++;
$shuffle_count = $count;
    $shuffle_firstname = htmlentities($result['firstname']);
    $shuffle_lastname = htmlentities($result['lastname']);
    $shuffle_id = htmlentities($result['id']);
    $shuffle_username = htmlentities($result['username']);
    $shuffle_email = htmlentities($result['email']);
?>
    <input type="hidden" name="count[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_count; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="firstname[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_firstname; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="lastname[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_lastname; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_id; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="username[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_username; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="email[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_email; ?
    >">

    <?php 

        endforeach;
```

Javascript

```
var displayResults = function(data){
                var i = 0;
                var lineheight = 24;
                var time = 3000;
                var interval = setInterval(function(){ 
                    if( i <= data.length){ 
                        console.log( data[i] ); 
                        $('#results').append('<div class="result">' +
                                    //'<div class="shuffle_results">' + data[i].firstname + ' ' + data[i].lastname + '</div>' + 
                                    '<div class="shuffle_results">' + data[i].drafted_order + ' '+ data[i].firstname + ' ' + data[i].lastname + '</div>' + 
                                    '<input type="hidden" name="count[]" value="' + data[i].drafted_order + '">' +
                                    '<input type="hidden" name="firstname[]" value="' + data[i].firstname + '">' +
                                    '<input type="hidden" name="lastname[]" value="' + data[i].lastname + '">' +
                                    '<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="' + data[i].id + '">' +
                                    '<input type="hidden" name="username[]" value="' + data[i].username + '">' +
                                    '<input type="hidden" name="email[]" value="' + data[i].email + '">' +
                                '</div>');
                       var $this = $('.shuffle_results:last'); 
                        $this.show().animate({ 
                            'left': 0 + 'px', 
                            'bottom': + '0px' 
                            //$(document).height() - (lineheight * data.length)
                        }, { 
                            duration: time 
                        });
                    i++;
                    } else { 
                        clearInterval(interval); 
                    } 
                }, 3000); 
            };
```

I get this error..

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'drafted_order' of undefined.
```

I have tried to change these two lines..

```
'<div class="shuffle_results">' + data[i].drafted_order + ' '+ data[i].firstname + ' ' + data[i].lastname + '</div>' + 
    '<input type="hidden" name="count[]" value="' + data[i].drafted_order + '">' +
```

To this:

```
'<div class="shuffle_results">' + data[i].count + ' '+ data[i].firstname + ' ' + data[i].lastname + '</div>' + 
    '<input type="hidden" name="count[]" value="' + data[i].count + '">' +
```

However, it did not fix the issue, the same error populated. What am I doing wrong to get this count to display?

UPDATE: added.

```
$(function(){  
                $('form[name="form"]').on('submit', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                   $.post('shuffle_results.php', function(data){ 
                    var o = $.parseJSON(data); 
                    displayResults(o); 
                    });
                    });
                });
```

PHP for displayresults(o)

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `group` = 3");
$array = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
$array[] = array( 
'id' => $row['id'],
'firstname' => $row['firstname'], 
'lastname' => $row['lastname'], 
'username' => $row['username'], 
'email' => $row['email'] 
); 

if (isset($_POST['shuffle'])) {

    }
}
shuffle($array);
    echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: change `if( i <= data.length){ `  to `if( i < data.length){`

Comment: Didn't help. Thanks though.

Comment: Well `data[i]` is undefined

Comment: @epascarello I am not sure what to change it to so that it is defined. I'm giving it the name property.

Comment: How is `data` defined? Not enough info to help you.

Comment: @epascarello I added another block of code I have. Other than this, there is nothing else to it. Everything else works besides this except, not all of my names that are outputted go through the animation, but that will have to be another question.

Comment: and is `o` an array? What is the value of `i` when it errors and @AshishKumar is correct above.

Comment: Yes, o is an array. I added my php that it is calling to

Comment: What are the debugging lines saying about `data[i]`? How about showing us what `o` got there?

Comment: What can I add in to debug it?

Comment: You are already doing it: `console.log( data[i] );` that must throw undefined at some point. Do the same but for `data` to inspect the whole thing.

Comment: So this? `console.log( data[] );`

Comment: @MinusFour Yes it does throw undefined, it outputs that onto the page.

Comment: There is nothing in the console. This is what the source code looks like...`<div class="shuffle_results" style="left: 0px;">undefined Mike Calhoun</div><input type="hidden" name="count[]" value="undefined">`

Comment: Well if `data` is undefined then `o` is undefined. Which means there's a problem there with your `$.post` or `$.parseJSON`. Take a loot at `data` before being parsed out.

Comment: Could it be that I don't have $count in my array in my php file? The last bit of code I posted?

Comment: @MinusFour How can I do that?